# Need explanation on short code snippet

Tags: c, variables, type-conversion

I just made this short program. Can someone please explain why I am getting 2 as a result here?

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int variable;
    int a;
    a=variable;
    a=200;
    printf("%d",variable);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What value did you expect? 200?

Comment: yea i expected 200,but now i understand why it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the beginning, you *define* two variables, `a` and `variable`. Note, that those variables at this point are not *initialized*. Right now, the compiler only knows that there are two variables of type `int` and their names, nothing more.

You then try to *initialize* variable `a` with the *not initialized* variable `variable`, the result should be clear: The two variables remain uninitialized.

Then you proceed and initialize `a` with `200`, `variable` is still only defined, not initialized.

After that, you print the still uninitialized variable `variable`, which hasn't recieved any "real" value as of yet, only what already was "lying around" in memory when the compiler assigned that memory location to the variable. In your case, that was "2" (or at least, that's what `printf` could extract from there).

Further reading: [C Variables](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_variables.htm). This explains how variables are defined, declared and initialized.

Comment: Thanks man, I got it now

Comment: @kanishktanwar: If your problem is solved, please consider accepting one of the answers you recieved by clicking the tick that appears next to them. That way you'll mark this question as "solved" (or "has an accepted answer" in StackOverflow terms).

Answer (score 5):

Because you print the value of an uninitialized variable. It will have an *indeterminate* (and seemingly random) value.

The assignment you make to `a` just copies the value of `variable` and then of `200` into `a`. The value of `variable` remains unmodified and indeterminate.

I recommend you [find a good beginners book or two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to read.

Answer (score 2):

Assigment operator (a = variable;) does not link the two variables, just assignes whatever value there is in the righthandside expression to the left handside.

You can visualize local variables as boxes where you can put values into.

Comment: This should be a comment

Answer (score 0):

In c if you don't assign a value to the variable then it stores the garbage value which can be anything.In your code you did not assign the value to variable so it print 2 (which can be anything)